# Integration Using Spherical Coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, integration, geometry, moment-of-inertia

So I had to find the moment of inertia of a hollow sphere of mass $M$, radius $R$, and negligible thickness.

$dI=R^2 \cdot dm$

where $dm = \dfrac{M}{4\pi R^2}\cdot R^2\sin(\theta)\cdot d\theta\cdot d\phi$

so $dI=\dfrac{MR^2}{4\pi}\sin(\theta)d\theta\cdot d\phi$

however, I am getting $\int _0^{\pi }\int _0^{2\pi }\frac{mr^2}{4\pi }\sin \left(y\right)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=mR^2$ which is not the correct answer of $I=2/3 MR^2$.

Comment: Where is your origin? And did you integrate over the radius?

Comment: My origin is at the center of the sphere and the axis of rotation is any axis passing through the center.

Comment: Perhaps you can show the steps of your integration? The error is not immediate to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment of inertia is defined as $I\equiv\int\rho|\vec{r}^2|dV$. You've correctly derived the mass density $$\rho(r) = \frac{M}{4\pi R^2}\delta(r-R).$$  Note, though, that $\vec{r}$ is the distance from the axis of rotation to the point $dV$; in this case $|\vec{r}|=R\sin\theta$ in spherical coordinates.  If you push through the integration you'll find the correct answer, $I_{\mathrm{spherical \, shell}} = (2/3)MR^2$.  (NB: $I_{\mathrm{solid \, sphere}} = (2/5)MR^2$.)

Comment: Thanks. Finally got it correct. Also edited the problem with correct formula for moment of inertia.